# How to enable cookies in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, cookie

How to Enable cookies in Magento 2.x?

Where can you configure Cookies in Magento 2.0?

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Magento Admin > Stores > Settings / Configuration > General / Web > Default Cookie Settings**

[image]